# npm install fails, yarn install succeeds on netlify deploy

Tags: npm, eslint, gatsby, yarnpkg, netlify

OK, so I have been trying to fix this error which appearred after I changed my package-lock file:[image: error]
I was able to resolve this error by doing `yarn add eslint && gatsby develop`. Why does `yarn install && gatsby develop` work after removing package-lock, npm_modules, and .cache but `npm install && gatsby develop` results in this error?

```
TypeError: Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null
5:05:47 PM:   
5:05:47 PM:   - CssDependency.js:12 Object.<anonymous>
5:05:47 PM:     [repo]/[mini-css-extract-plugin]/dist/CssDependency.js:12:46
```

I'm looking to understand the solution of using `yarn install` although I never used yarn for this project until `npm install && gatsby develop` resulted in the error above.

Comment: You shouldn't change your `package-lock` or `yarn-lock file`, it is created based on your `package.json`  in each yarn install or `npm install`. I guess the error comes from there, a missing dependency or something like this in your repository. Check if some of these files are ignored and your Netlify environment does not know the new changed you do.

Comment: Check also yarn/npm versions between your server and you local environment.

Comment: @FerranBuireu build fails locally. I was suggested to delete .cache, npm_modules, and package-lock, but it would still always error out until I tried yarn.

Which files do I check and how do I check if they're ignored?

Comment: I focused my question more on local development rather than deployment.

Comment: I faced the same issue (or at least the same error message) a few days ago and it was caused due to different yarn versions between my local machine (1.21) and my deployment server (1.22). In your case, it seems caused by some dependencies installed in a different way using npm and yarn...