# Yarn Install fails due to non existing file

Tags: reactjs, npm, deployment, yarnpkg, netlify

I am deploying a site to netlify.
The site deployed fine until I installed `react-player` using `npm install react-player`
There were a number of critical errors that I tried to fix.

The site builds fine locally using `yarn run build` and it runs fine locally doing `npm start`.

But when I deploy it to netlify I get an error with `Yarn Install` that shows the following

```
5:21:48 AM: Build ready to start
5:21:50 AM: build-image version: 73def8bb10593b9b818f44989a75ea508018ccb7 (focal)
5:21:50 AM: build-image tag: v4.5.2
5:21:50 AM: buildbot version: 8cd320132979d1a1a502e85e77b47b97cc7d659f
5:21:50 AM: Fetching cached dependencies
5:21:50 AM: Starting to download cache of 237.2MB
5:21:52 AM: Finished downloading cache in 2.467525285s
5:21:52 AM: Starting to extract cache
5:22:00 AM: Finished extracting cache in 7.81313843s
5:22:00 AM: Finished fetching cache in 10.326357005s
5:22:00 AM: Starting to prepare the repo for build
5:22:01 AM: Preparing Git Reference refs/heads/main
5:22:02 AM: Parsing package.json dependencies
5:22:03 AM: Starting build script
5:22:03 AM: Installing dependencies
5:22:03 AM: Python version set to 2.7
5:22:03 AM: Started restoring cached node version
5:22:05 AM: Finished restoring cached node version
5:22:05 AM: v16.13.2 is already installed.
5:22:06 AM: Now using node v16.13.2 (npm v8.1.2)
5:22:06 AM: Started restoring cached build plugins
5:22:06 AM: Finished restoring cached build plugins
5:22:06 AM: Attempting ruby version 2.7.2, read from environment
5:22:07 AM: Using ruby version 2.7.2
5:22:07 AM: Using PHP version 8.0
5:22:07 AM: Started restoring cached yarn cache
5:22:12 AM: Finished restoring cached yarn cache
5:22:13 AM: No yarn workspaces detected
5:22:13 AM: Started restoring cached node modules
5:22:13 AM: Finished restoring cached node modules
5:22:13 AM: Installing NPM modules using Yarn version 1.22.10
5:22:14 AM: yarn install v1.22.10
5:22:14 AM: warning package-lock.json found. Your project contains lock files generated by tools other than Yarn. It is advised not to mix package managers in order to avoid resolution inconsistencies caused by unsynchronized lock files. To clear this warning, remove package-lock.json.
5:22:14 AM: [1/4] Resolving packages...
5:22:15 AM: warning react-scripts > fsevents@2.1.2: "Please update to latest v2.3 or v2.2"
5:22:15 AM: warning react-scripts > webpack-dev-server > chokidar > fsevents@1.2.13: fsevents 1 will break on node v14+ and could be using insecure binaries. Upgrade to fsevents 2.
5:22:15 AM: warning react-scripts > babel-jest > @jest/transform > jest-haste-map > fsevents@1.2.13: fsevents 1 will break on node v14+ and could be using insecure binaries. Upgrade to fsevents 2.
5:22:15 AM: error Package "chokidar2" refers to a non-existing file '"/opt/build/repo/chokidar2"'.
5:22:15 AM: info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation about this command.
5:22:15 AM: Error during Yarn install
5:22:15 AM: Build was terminated: Build script returned non-zero exit code: 1
5:22:15 AM: Creating deploy upload records
5:22:15 AM: Failing build: Failed to build site
5:22:15 AM: Failed during stage 'building site': Build script returned non-zero exit code: 1
5:22:15 AM: Finished processing build request in 25.380006101s
```

I am not sure how to approach solving this error. I have checked a number of similar posts such as [npm install fails, yarn install succeeds on netlify deploy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61219458/npm-install-fails-yarn-install-succeeds-on-netlify-deploy) but I am not finding a good solution.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

the issue was in the `yarn.lock` file. It was referring to `chokidar2` which was not working.

I removed the `yarn.lock` file and my `node modules` folder.

Then I ran `yarn cache clean`

then I reran `yarn install` to reinstall `node modules`

Then I ran `yarn run build`

and reuploaded everything to `git` with the new build